# Using CSS to select parent of an element

Tags: css

Can I use CSS to select a parent of an element without using jQuery or JavaScript (pure CSS).

Here is my code

```
<nav>
    <ul class='page-numbers'>
        <li><span class='page-numbers current'>1</span></li>
        <li><a class='page-numbers' href=/page/2/'>2</a></li>
        <li><a class='page-numbers' href=/page/3/'>3</a></li>
        <li><a class="next page-numbers" href="/page/2/">Next Page</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Please note that there is a class called **current**, and in the example above, it is on the first page. This **current** class will be inserted into any page that is the current page (so if the current page is the second page, the second item in the list will have the **current** class.

Now using CSS only (without jQuery or JavaScript), how can I select the list element that has a child with the class current?

Please do not suggest changing the HTML because it should be the way it is because this is the requirement.

Comment: you can't select the parent with css

Comment: Why not just set a class on the `li`?  It appears you have the ability to add it to your anchor tag classes.

Comment: I do not have control over the html, it is used by other users and this is the design needed.

Comment: It is now 2023. selecting a parent with css is possible. Please follow the link above the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: @horace - How things change in 10 years, eh?

Comment: I am stunned =)

Answer (score 1):

You basically cannot do it just with CSS, you will have to use javascript, as can be seen in this this old question with a lot of votes: [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/938236). (checked that the answer is about CSS 3 as well as CSS 2).

Comment: All I have to say is :(

Comment: BTW, I knew it as I was looking for the same thing recently and was also disappointed...

Comment: Thanks. I will try finding another way throug CSS, if not I may have to use jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

Did you have a look at the url http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/